# Adwords PHP Client Library Examples won't connect?

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I'm working with the 201109 version in the sandbox and getting this error when navigating to examples/v201109/GetAllCampaigns.php

```
AuthenticationError.CLIENT_CUSTOMER_ID_INVALID @ ; trigger:'client_1+email' Service[CampaignService.get]
```

(removed email)

if i change the clientId in auth.ini to

```
clientId = "2"
```

I get a different error

```
AuthenticationError.CUSTOMER_NOT_FOUND @ ; trigger:'2' Service[CampaignService.get]
```

and if i comment the the clientId line out, It tells me i have no Campaigns.

By going to the AddCampaign.php example,with the line commented out still i get this error

```
[OperationAccessDenied.ADD_OPERATION_NOT_PERMITTED @ operations[0]]
```

I've looked all these errors up but they don't seem to give me much indication of what i should be doing.
Has the default format for the automated campaigns changed? Am i even connected to the sandbox? So confused! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The use of client emails in the request was deprecated in v201109, and client customer IDs must be used instead.  More information is available here:

http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/sandbox.html#getting-started

Comment: great thanks. So it how do i use ServicedAccountService.get()? i keep getting this `Fatal error: Call to undefined function get() in /var/www/_sandbox/jacqui/aw_api_php_lib_2.7.1/examples/v201109/PauseCampaign.php on line 19`

Comment: Have there been any other changes that would be causing these errors in the sandbox since  [your tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/v/Idvia4600_E&hl=en_US&fs=1&hd=1) thanks for your time